# How to fix magento2 upgrade issue

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.2.4

I try to upgrade `2.1.9` to `2.2.4`
but got this error on site:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface
>   Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface in
>   vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php

Comment: yes I tried removing var/cache and var/generation also change mode..but still same error

Comment: are you on developer mode